# Hi, I´m trying to make a DataFrame with a lot of data for each column, but the code I use it´s not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I´m using thos code

```
data = {'Coef. de Agrupamiento': [clust],
        'Grado': [gra],
        'Id': [node]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Id','Coef. de Agrupamiento', 'Grado'])
df
```

[But i obtain a dataframe with only one row with my two columns, but in each column, all the values of my variables are in a row.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGdl2.png)

[I want something like this, but with all the values of my variables (they are 85)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4g0P.png)

```
data = {'Coef. de Agrupamiento': [clust[0],clust[1], clust[3]],
        'Grado': [gra[0],gra[1],gra[2]],
        'Id': [node[0],node[1],node[2]]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Id','Coef. de Agrupamiento', 'Grado'])
df
```

But my question is if there is a way to tell python to use each value of my variable without indexing each one by hand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're having this problem because you've passed the variables as lists. Try removing the square brackets [] from  your 'data' element. This should solve your problem.